# Accessing a typedef structure inside another typedef struct

Tags: c, file, struct, header, typedef

Kindly, see the below given snippet. How can we access the `descrptn` from the `struct sample`, using the `struct storage`?

```
typedef struct {
char hex;
char descrptn[50];
}TypeText;

typedef struct {
int val;
TypeText test[10];
}TypePara;

static const TypeText sample[]={
{0x00,  "Low"},
{0x7F,  "Mid"},
{0xFF,  "HIgh"},
};

const TypePara storage[]= {
   {0, sample},
   {1, sample}   
};
```

Comment: Neither `storage` nor `sample` is a struct.  Both are arrays.

Comment: But in any event, your code is invalid and does not compile, so the only possible answers to the question as posed are variations on "you don't."

Comment: Instead of improving the question you added one irrelevant tag and one deprecated tag.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hows it invalid? This is a valid header file part.

Comment: @Mahi, have you *tried* to compile it?  A conforming compiler will reject the initializer for variable `storage`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger How can it be rectified?

Comment: Moreover, although it's not a matter of validity, it is almost never appropriate to have variable definitions in a header file.  *Declarations*, yes.  *Definitions*, no.

Comment: @Mahi, there are infinitely many ways to convert your code into something that compiles. The very simplest would be to delete the file's entire contents, but surely that's not a useful direction.  Another possibility would be to change the type of `TypePara.test` to `TypeText *`, but it's unclear whether that's appropriate.  I cannot advise you with any certainty because I can't tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Although arrays can be initialized with variables at compile time, ( _[see VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) )_, a struct cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found my solution, in this way:

```
        typedef struct {
            int age;
            int RollNo;
            int Rank;
            char Name[10];
        }TypeStudent;

        typedef struct {
            char class_name[20];
            TypeStudent *Students;
        }TypeClass;

        int main()
        {

             const TypeStudent  Stu_Details[] = {
             { 3,   1,  18, "Mahesh"},
             { 3,   1,   7,  "Kumar"}
            };

              const TypeClass Class_Details[]= {
             { "Class 10",     Stu_Details},  //two students details
             { "Class 8",                0}   //no student details attached
            };

            printf("\r\nTest: %d",Class_Details[0].Students->Rank);
            printf("\r\nTest: %d",(Class_Details[0].Students+1)->Rank);

            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question *How can we access the descrptn from the struct sample, using the struct storage?* is addressed in the main function of the corrected code below, but because of some incorrect assumptions on the shape of your compound struct, it may not look like what you assumed it would.

First there are some syntax errors and wrong assumptions that need to be addressed.

*1)* -  Note:  Because you are initializing an element of a constant expression to 0xFF,  even though its alignment within the initializer should identify it as a `signed char`, depending on your compiler and its settings, it might assume an `unsigned char` and warn of an overflow. (This is precisely what happens on my system).  Because the value is actually aligned with a `signed char`, at run-time an overflow should not occur.
*2)* - You have an array of `struct`.  Although a simple array can be initialized with a variable ( the *[Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)* concept has been valid since C99. ), A *struct* can only be initialized with constant values.  Because your code attempts to initialize a struct (`sample`) with a variable, it should fail to compile.
*3)* -The shape of a struct initializer must match the shape of the struct it is initializing, including initializer position and type.  Because TypePara is a compound struct (a struct containing a struct member) its initializer must take that into account.  Your initializer for `const TypePara storage[] ={...}` is not shaped correctly.

The first two items should be clearly flagged for you with compile time messages.  Make sure you have your compiler set to see them.

The third item, unfortunately will not always show up as an error, or  warning.  C will sometimes let you do things that are not necessarily correct.

Each of these is addressed below, in syntax and comments.

Using your `struct` definitions, with the following indicated changes, you can access `descrptn` like this:  (The following is a complete and compilable adaptation of your original post)

```
typedef struct {   //Note:                                             
char hex;          //Initializer for TypeText shaped like this:        
char descrptn[50]; //hex         description    
}TypeText;         //{0x01,      "one"}; 

typedef struct {   //Note:  TypePara is a struct containing an array of struct
int val;           //Initializer for each instance of TypePara shaped like this:
TypeText test[10]; //val  TypeText[0]   TypeText[1]     TypeText[9]
}TypePara;         //{1, {0x01, "one"},{0x02, "two"}...{0x0A, "Ten"}};

static const TypeText sample[]={

    {0x00,  "Low"},
    {0x49,  "Mid"},
  //{0xFF,  "HIgh"} //commented and replaced to 
    {0x7F,  "High"} //prevent possible overflow condition
};

//const TypePara storage[]= {
//   {0, sample}, //error, "sample is not a compile time constant
//   {1, sample}   
//};

//Note: illustrates shape only.  Values are otherwise meaningless
const TypePara storage[] = {
    { 0,{{0x00, "zero"},{0x01, "one"},{0x02, "two"},{0x03, "three"},{0x04, "four"},{0x05, "five"},{0x06, "six"},{0x07, "seven"},{0x08, "eight"},{0x09, "nine"}}},
    { 1,{{0x01, "zero"},{0x11, "one"},{0x12, "two"},{0x13, "three"},{0x14, "four"},{0x15, "five"},{0x16, "six"},{0x17, "seven"},{0x18, "eight"},{0x19, "nine"}}},
    { 2,{{0x02, "zero"},{0x21, "one"},{0x22, "two"},{0x23, "three"},{0x24, "four"},{0x25, "five"},{0x26, "six"},{0x27, "seven"},{0x28, "eight"},{0x29, "nine"}}},
    { 3,{{0x03, "zero"},{0x31, "one"},{0x32, "two"},{0x33, "three"},{0x34, "four"},{0x35, "five"},{0x36, "six"},{0x37, "seven"},{0x38, "eight"},{0x39, "nine"}}},
    { 4,{{0x04, "zero"},{0x41, "one"},{0x42, "two"},{0x43, "three"},{0x44, "four"},{0x45, "five"},{0x46, "six"},{0x47, "seven"},{0x48, "eight"},{0x49, "nine"}}}
};


int main(void)
{
    //Accessing descrptn   
    printf( "descrptn is %s\n", storage[0].test[0].descrptn);
    printf( "descrptn is %s\n", storage[0].test[1].descrptn);
    printf( "descrptn is %s\n", storage[0].test[2].descrptn);
    printf( "descrptn is %s\n", storage[0].test[3].descrptn);
    //...
    //This can continue as you have 5 storage elements
    //defined, each of those containing 10 test elements.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice - I didn't spot the missing initialisers. Might need extra `{...}` around the nested `struct` init to be strictly conforming?

Comment: @WeatherVane - I did not get any warnings, but agree, if for nothing else, then readability.

Comment: ...and highlights the issue. I posted an answer recently that lacked them, it compiled for me but the OP complained it did not.

Comment: @WeatherVane, paragraph 6.7.9/20 of the standard specifies behavior for when the initializer of a sub-aggregate is not enclosed in braces, so I don't think omitting them causes the code to fail to conform.  But that will elicit *warnings* from many compilers -- or errors if warnings are treated as such.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks, perhaps that other question's OP failed on a warning.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Would you mind posting a link to the other question you cite?

Comment: Sorry, I have looked at all my answers in October and that objection is not there. It was fairly recent, so it must have been a comment exchange, or a deleted question.

Comment: @WeatherVane - okay, thanks.  Was just going to see if my compiler(s) would pick anything up.  I use NI, CLANG, and GCC (bundled with Code::Blocks).  I get different compile results from same code often between these three.  Settings between the three, I am sure, is the reason I see inconsistent results.

Comment: As far as I recall, it was a 2D array that I initialised with `...{0}` and after the objection I suggested `...{{0,},}` but I heard nothing back.

Comment: this comment: `//Note: range of char is -128 to 127.  0xFF is 255.` is in error.  given a signed char (not always true on all systems) the value `0xFF` will be seen as `-1` so may raise a warning but should compile

Comment: @user3629249 - You are right, The comment as is, is misleading. I will change it.  Because of the way it is being used, (i.e. as an initializer within a constant expression) it can be interpreted by a compiler as an `unsigned char`, which is what my compiler did.  The code actually ran, but the warning did appear at compile time. Thanks for pointing out the bad wording.

Answer (score 1):

If you want hex values, you should have `unsigned char` or `uint_8`, and not char (0xff is negative). Also i suppose you only want a *TypeText* in each *TypePara* and not a array, but this should help to fix your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char hex;
    char descrptn[50];
} TypeText;

typedef struct {
    int val;
    TypeText *test;
} TypePara;

static TypeText sample[]={

{0x00,  "Low"},
{0x7F,  "Mid"},
{0xFF,  "HIgh"}

};

TypePara storage[]= {
   {0, &sample[0]},
   {1, &sample[1]}   
};


int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", storage[0].test->descrptn);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Index for `test`?

Comment: This does not compile for me, nor does it appear that it should.

Comment: My bad, i was working with something else with c++11, i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the initialization of the `storage` array, the type of `sample` is a *"pointer to a const TypeText"*. Thus, to make that initialization work, you need a pointer to a `const Typetext` in the `TypePara` structure. So the definition of the `TypePara` structure should look like this

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
    const TypeText *array;
}
TypePara;
```

Here's a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char hex;
    char description[50];
}
TypeText;

typedef struct
{
    int value;
    const TypeText *array;
}
TypePara;

static const TypeText sample[]=
{
    { 0x00,  "Low"  },
    { 0x7F,  "Mid"  },
    { 0xFF,  "High" }
};

const TypePara storage[]=
{
    { 0, sample },
    { 1, sample }
};

int main( void )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        printf( "storage with value %d:\n", storage[i].value );
        for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
            printf( "   hex=%02x description='%s'\n", storage[i].array[j].hex, storage[i].array[j].description );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear: that makes the elements of `storage` contain *pointers to* array `sample`, not array `sample` itself.  This is an important distinction.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed, as you pointed out there are infinite possibilities. I took the approach of making the two initializations work as is, by adjusting the struct definitions. ryyker took the opposite approach of using the struct definitions as is, and adjusting the initializations as necessary. I leave it to the OP decide which approach suits his needs.

Comment: Yes, what you present is valid, and one of the most likely alternatives for what the OP actually wants.  I am nitpicking your wording because I think it especially important to be precise with someone (i.e. the OP) who seems to be a bit fuzzy on some of the basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

```
storage[index].test[index].descrptn
```

Should work.

Comment: Will not work, because the OP's code is invalid to begin with.  Nothing works with it.

Comment: @John Bollinger My bad. I made the assumption that OP was just giving a (rather poor) example. Guess this is why one shouldn't assume.

Comment: If the structs were initialized correctly, your syntax is perfect and answers primary question.